# Minimum dimensions for a hotel room in the UK

Tags: england-and-wales, regulations

Are there any laws in England which dictate the minimum size a hotel room has to be so it can be rented out?

I can only find information on renting of homes etc.

Comment: I'm curious if there is a minimum size - I've spent about four years during the past ten years 'living' in hotels in UK and across Europe.  My understanding is windows/exit and distance to fire exit and smoke detectors in rooms are defined in law, but the physical size of the room is not.

Comment: Usually, the limitation would arise via the "back door" of building code requirements. I don't have access to any U.K. building codes, however.

Answer (score 1):

**NO**: but it's extremely difficulty to prove a negative, however according to [Which?](https://www.which.co.uk/news/article/does-premier-inns-new-micro-hotel-room-offer-good-value-aIJqZ2A9DxTp#:%7E:text=There%27s%20no%20minimum%20size%20requirement,be%20at%20least%2013sq%20metres.)<sup>1</sup>:

> What does the law say?
>
> There's no minimum size requirement for a hotel room in the UK, aside from in Northern Ireland where double rooms must be at least 13sq metres.

Note that the reference to [northern-ireland](/questions/tagged/northern-ireland) is incomplete. Schedule 1, paragraph 8(d) of the [Categories of Tourist Establishment (Statutory Criteria) Regulations (Northern Ireland) 1992](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/nisr/1992/149/made) ([as amended](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/nisr/2009/367/contents/made)) state that bedrooms shall have:

> A floor area (excluding and ensuite bathroom) of -
>
> (i) in the case of a single room not less than 7.50 square metres; or
>
> (ii) in the case of a double bedroom not less than 13.00 square metres...

---

<sup>1</sup>[Which?](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Which%3F) is the brand name of the Consumers' Association - a "watchdog" that promotes informed consumer choice, product safety etc